# Getting a resource file as an InputStream in Playframework

Tags: java, playframework

```
Play.classloader.getResourceAsStream(filepath);
```

filepath - relative to what? project root? playframework root? absolute path?

Or maybe the usage Play.classloader.getResourceAsStream is wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the Play Framework the "conf" directory is on the classpath, so you can put your file there and open it with getResourceAsStream.

For example if you create a file "conf/foo.txt" you can open it using

```
Play.classloader.getResourceAsStream("foo.txt");
```

Comment: What if the file isn't a configuration file?

Comment: It does not matter if the file is not a configuration file, you can still put it in the conf directory and access it this way.

Comment: Sorry, my point was that you should not be putting non-configuration-related files in the conf directory. It's messy and confusing for other developers looking at your code.

Comment: Yes I agree it is not ideal from a readability point of view. To make it a bit more obvious you could create a subdirectory under conf with a name that makes clear what these files are for. And I suppose you could argue that any read-only, non-code files like these, no matter what they are used for, are a kind of "configuration" in the broad sense of that word.

Comment: I suppose you could, but it still seems a bit dirty to me. I added an alternative in another answer below (using the public folder) but it's not perfect either. I think Play 2 needs to add a folder for private assets/resources that can be accessible in production mode.

Comment: I like the "public" version too.  It does seem like a better solution for non config files. I gave your answer a vote!

Comment: Does this work in development mode? I always get file not found.

Comment: Not available for Play 2.3

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer is deprecated in Play 2.5.x as global access to things like a classloader is slowly being phased out.  The recommended way to handling this moving forward is to inject a `play.api.Environment` then using its `classLoader` to get the `InputStream`, e.g.

```
class Controller @Inject()(env: Environment, ...){

  def readFile = Action {  req =>
    ...

    //if the path is bad, this will return null, so best to wrap in an Option
    val inputStream = Option(env.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(path))

    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: your answer looks like scala, not java

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative to using the `conf` dir (which should only be used for configuration-related files), you can use the `public` dir and access it with:

```
 Play.classloader.getResourceAsStream("public/foo.txt")
```

Or in Scala with:

```
 Play.resourceAsStream("public/foo.txt")
```

Comment: Does this make the file publicly accessible to anyone who has the URL?

Comment: That is something to consider--this approach would not be appropriate for resources that you don't want to make public.

Answer (score 5):

Inject `Environment` and then call `environment.resourceAsStream("filename");`

Example:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class ExampleResource extends Controller{

     private final Environment environment;
     
     @Inject
     public ExampleResource(Environment environment){
          this.environment = environment;
     }

     public void readResourceAsStream() {
          InputStream resource = environment.resourceAsStream("filename");
          // Do what you want with the stream here
     }
}
```

Documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.0/api/java/play/Environment.html#resourceAsStream-java.lang.String-

Answer (score -2):

Relative to the classpath root. That is, your `WEB-INF/classes` + all the jars in `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: so playframework-wise it could be in the "lib" folder inside the project? and the path to getResourceAsStream would be just "/filename"?

Comment: it can't be in /lib. It should be in a jar there.

Comment: I put it in a jar.. still - doesn't work. 
Is there a different convention or way to relate to resources on Playframework architecture?

Comment: try putting it in `WEB-INF/classes`

Comment: how did you 'sent' the file to getResourceAsStream?