# How to access a txt file in a Play app?

Tags: playframework, java-8

I'm struggling to access stopwords.txt, a list of stopwords my `StopWordRemover` class is using. I can access it just fine using its relative path "`./stopwords.txt`" when I run `StopWordRemover` as a standalone class, but when I try to use it in the Play application I keep getting FileNotFound Exceptions.

I've also tried:

- moving it into the public folder, and accessing it using controllers.routes.Assets.at(...)
- moving it into the conf folder

^Neither worked.

Where am I going wrong?

Relevant method:

```
private static void initStopWordList() {
        if (stopWords == null) {
            stopWordFilePath = "/stopwords.txt";
            stopWords = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(stopWordFilePath));
                stream.forEach(stopWords::add);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Directory path:

```
app/
    service/
        StopWordRemover
    stopwords.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I put it in the `config` folder.

Then you need to get it as a Resource **not a File**:

In Scala, for example:

`private val stream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/stopwords.txt")`

Here some other versions you can try:

`getClass.getResourceAsStream("stopwords.txt")` or on windows `getClass.getResourceAsStream("\stopwords.txt")`

From here [getting-a-resource-file-as-an-inputstream-in-playframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888343/getting-a-resource-file-as-an-inputstream-in-playframework):

```
class Controller @Inject()(env: Environment, ...){

  def readFile = Action {  req =>
    ...

    //if the path is bad, this will return null, so best to wrap in an Option
    val inputStream = Option(env.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/stopwords.txt"))

    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work! 
`InputStream in = StopWordRemover.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/stopwords.txt");` assigns a null value to `in`'.

Comment: Strange, maybe the classloader is the Problem?
I added some other versions to my answer. The only difference I see is that you get the ClassLoader from `StopWordRemover.class.getClass()` as I do from `getClass()`

Just to be sure: `stopwords.txt` is in `conf`?