# How to read resources in test code with Play Framework?

Tags: scala, testing, playframework

## Question

I could not find how to include resources in test code with Play Framework.

I want to write getResource code @/test/controllers/HomeControllerSpec.scala as follows.

```
"HomeController Test" should {
  val inputStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("test.json")
  ...
}
```

But this code require that "test.json" is placed in target directory.
I found a way to use Inject and play.api.Environment but this method do not work well in test code.

[Getting a resource file as an InputStream in Playframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888343/getting-a-resource-file-as-an-inputstream-in-playframework)

Are there any best practice to read resources in test code?

## Additional Information

I tried the following code @ /play/test/controllers/HomeControllerSpec.scala

```
val source = getClass.getResource("/").getPath
println(source.toString())
```

And I also got the following result (/play is the root of play project).

```
/play/target/scala-2.12/test-classes/
```

Generally, /target is ignored (written in .gitignore). So I want to know the way to read text files in Play test code (placed in /test).

## Solution (solved. Thanks your comments and help.)

I tried the following command

```
sbt "show test:resourceDirectory"
```

and got the following result.

```
/play/test/resources
```

This means that files placed in this directory are used as resources and copied to target directory (/play/target/scala-2.12/test-classes in my case). So I put the test.json at

/play/test/resources/test.json

and could read this file by the following code.

```
val source = getClass.getResource("/test.json").getPath
val code = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/test.json")
println("getPath of test.json: "+ source)
println("text of test.json: " + IOUtils.toString(code))
```

Output

```
getPath of test.json: /play/target/scala-2.12/test- 
classes/test.json
text of test.json: {
     "key": "value"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by resource? You mean a file you added to the `/public` folder? Or some resource you can find based on the route you defined within the `routes`?

Comment: In other words where is the `test.json` file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access test resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285898/how-to-access-test-resources)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your project directory structure (Play Framework)

- /

  - /app
  - /conf
  - /test

    - test.json
    - /controllers

      - HomeControllerSpec.scala

### The reason why you cannot access `test.json` from `/test`

- Any files other than '*.scala' in the source path (`/app`, `/test`) are excluded.
- `test.json` in `/test` is excluded when compiled.

### Alternative way

Put `test.json` in `/test/resources`

- /

  - /app
  - /conf
  - /test

    - /resources

      - test.json
    - /controllers

      - HomeControllerSpec.scala

### Read Also

- [Resource directory for tests in a Play application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762969/resource-directory-for-tests-in-a-play-application)